# Extract Doxygen functions along with namespace into a .csv file

Tags: doxygen

While working with my Doxygen output doc, I've a requirement to extract all the functions into a spreadsheet. Additionally, each function had a requirement mapped to it using ALIASES defined in the configuration file. sample function as below:

> 

@requirement{req-id}

void Myfunc()

> 

I am able to see all the requirements documented in a separate page in my HTML output. But, I need to fetch the list of functions with respective requirement Ids into a .csv file for further processing. Could anyone please hep me out?

Thanks, Badri

Answer (score 1):

Doxygen has no irect CSV output.
You would need the XML output (`GENERATE_XML=YES`) and process the resulting file into a format you want / directly process the file without the need of a CSV file.

When you have an `ALIASES` like

```
ALIASES += req{3}="\xrefitem req \"Requirement\" \"SW Requirements\" ID: \1 Requirement: \2 Verification Criteria: \3"
```

you will get a file `req.xml` that you can process further.

Comment: Thank you. This works. I set ('GENERATE_XML=YES') and I am able to get the requirement.xml in the output/xml folder, there I can find the required details like ID, function name, function reference ID etc..